# Unable to remove html content using JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am unable to remove the div with ID `"Third"` and display the result content in div with ID `"Fourth"`.
Please Note :- I need to append `#Third` content to `#Fourth` and then remove at later stage.

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="../jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom/js/jquery-1.10.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom/js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="../jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.css"
        rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            var widget = {}
            $("#Vshowdialog").click(function() {
                widget.doInitialize();
            });
            widget.doInitialize = function() {
                $("#Fourth").append($("#First").html());
                $("#Fourth").append($("#Second").html());
                $("#Fourth").append($("#Third").html());
                widget.showLightBox();
            };
            widget.showLightBox = function() {
            text = $('#Fourth').html();
            $(text).find("#Third").remove();
            $("#Fourth").dialog();
            };
        });
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" id="Vshowdialog" value="ShowDialog" />
    <div id="First">
        <div id="content">
            This is my main Firstcontent.</div>
        <div id="sidebar">
            This is a FirstSideBar</div>
    </div>
    <div id="Second">
        <div id="secondOne">
            This is my main Second content.</div>
        <div id="secondTwo">
            This is a second sidebar</div>
    </div>
    <div id="Third">
    hello
        <div id="thirdOne">
            This is my main third content.</div>
        <div id="thirdTwo">
            This is a third sidebar</div>
    </div>
    <div id="Fourth">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `text` is an HTML _string_, and you can't find elements in a string or remove them.

Comment: $('#thirdOne').html('');

Comment: $("#Third").remove() seems to be what you are looking for... without the find

Comment: As a rule when you are using dialogs from "in page" html, avoid using ids, because after opening the dialog you will have the same ids twice in the page. Consider switching to classes. Other than that there are lots of solutions you can use which lots of people have wrote in the answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
$('#Fourth').append($('#third'));
$('#thirdOne').unwrap();
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9fdw2/)**

or

```
$('#Fourth').append($('#Third')).find('#thirdOne').unwrap();
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3zWn4/)**

Answer (score 1):

```
 $(function() {
        var widget = {}
        $("#Vshowdialog").click(function() {
            widget.doInitialize();
        });
        widget.doInitialize = function() {
            $("#Fourth").append($("#First").html());
            $("#Fourth").append($("#Second").html());
            $("#Fourth").append($("#Third").html());
            widget.showLightBox();
        };
        widget.showLightBox = function() {
        $('#Fourth').find("#thirdOne").remove();
        $('#Fourth').find("#thirdTwo").remove();
        $("#Fourth").dialog();
        };
    });
```

Try this it will work fine.

Comment: "$("#Fourth").append($("#Third").html());" In this line you are appending the content of this div(id="Third"). So this div is not there. Thats why you are not able to find #Third .

Comment: Wrap you hello too in any span or div so that you can select the word.
That may be the easy way to get your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You're appending the "inner html" of the other elements to `#Fourth`; to keep the identifiers intact you should do this:

```
$('#First,#Second,#Third').appendTo('#Fourth');
```

Then, at a later stage you can simply remove `#Third`:

```
$('#Third').remove();
```

Comment: This removed the divs in outer html but i wanted the DOM to be removed only from the dialog

Comment: You could clone the elements first, but then you'd have duplicate ids so then you'd have to use classes to identify them.

Answer (score 0):

you'll want to initialize this variable

```
text = $('#Fourth').html();
```

But your looking for #Third within #Fourth when you only included the inner html, specificly

```
var text = $('#Fourth').html(); //contents of fourth
$(text).find("#Third").remove(); //third was added as inner Html without the wrapping container.
```

You should be able to just change

```
 $("#Fourth").append($("#Third").html());
```

to

```
 $("#Fourth").append($("#Third"));
```

The real question is why are you adding Third to Fourth and then removing it?  Your code is equivalent to this, in execution, assuming it was fixed.

```
$("#Fourth").append($("#Third"));
$("#Fourth").find("#Third").remove();
```

Comment: But this removes the outer html, I wanted to remove #Third only from the dialog that loads #Fourth

Comment: Why add it in the first place you execute widget.showLightBox(); just after adding it which removes it.  Maybe what you want is just the text() ?

Answer (score 0):

```
//cache the third div content
var tempThird = $('#Third');
//add your result to Fourth div
$('#Fourth').html("resultcontent");
//remove the third div
$('#Third').remove();
//tempThird will still have the essence of #Third div which you can use anywhere.
```

You can check the remove API documentation on http://api.jquery.com/remove/

Hope this solves your problem.